# Realizar consulta con $cond $sum, con mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Tengo el siguiente documento en mongodb:

```
{
  Iva:0.19,
  state:'Successfull',
  clientID:'N/A',
  payment:'Combined',
  seller:'60eadfafkla5we321d'
  consecutive:35612,
  secId:6,
  subtotal:8500,
  combined:true,
  pay_cash:4500,
  pay_card:4000    
}
```

y estoy realizando lo siguiente para obtener la suma si el payment es igual a *cash*, *card* o *combined*; en este caso este es el de *cash*:

```
    Totalcash:{
      $sum: {
        $cond: [
            {
              $eq: ['$payment', 'Cash'],
            },
             '$subtotal',
               0,
         ],
       }
    }
```

Me pregunto cómo podría hacer la condición para que no solo sume cuando el método de pago sea igual sino que sume también el valor de *pay_cash* cuando *pay_cash* sea mayor a 0. He intentado usar el `$or` dentro de `$cond` pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que lo que necesitas es el sumatorio total de todos los elementos de la colección, te adjunto una posible solución:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null, // Es null porque no lo agrupamos por ningun valor en conreto
      totalCash: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            { // El $or si funciona, es posible que por sintaxis no te funcionara bien
              $or: [ 
                { // Como se tiene que comprobar que sean varios parametros utilizo $in
                  $in: [ 
                    "$payment",
                    [ "Cash", "Card", "Combined" ]
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$pay_cash",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "$subtotal",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Te dejo un link donde he podido comprobar la query con algunos valores que me he inventado en base a tu documento: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aCD2y6qpcHj)

Espero que con esta query pueda ayudarte a resolver el problema, sino, no dudes en responder.

Un saludo!